What to do when moving away from Apple products
Apologies ahead of time if this is not the correct forum to ask this question:
My iPhone 10 is slowly dying (screen goes black for days, then will randomly come back just fine; Apple Store said $300 repair, not interested). I've decided to leave Apple products altogether (no hard feelings; just doing what the rest of the family does).
What steps do I need to take when exiting to make sure I have all my data (photos, contacts, etc.)?
I'm especially worried that I'm going to forget something, try to log in to iCloud with my AppleID and be unable to authenticate because I have no Apple product to enter the code on and/or it sends it to my defunct iPhone.
What measures should I take so that I will be able to access everything using non-Apple products only?

People manage Apple ID on windows with no Apple products other than online services. What is stopping you from setting up an alternate phone, contact information, emergency contact so you can always get into your AppleID? This might be better received if you make the step to move everything to android or be more clear what roadblocks you face. Also - when you say Apple products - it would help us help you to list exactly what products you need to consider. Apple TV, Mac, iPad, iPhone, services, etc….

Also, assuming you will be getting an Android-based phone (Samsung, Google, etc.) I have heard  there are apps on both the iPhone and Android side that help you transfer your data from an iPhone to an Android phone, just like Apple offers an Android app to transfer data from Android to iPhone.

Apple suggest following these steps Archive or make copies of the information you store in iCloud.
Data and privacy
A more complete approach is to export all your data via https://privacy.apple.com

Obtain a copy of your data
Download a copy of your data from Apple apps and services, which may include purchase or app usage history, and data you store with Apple.
Request a copy of your data ›

…

Please select the data you would like to download, and we will prepare a copy for you. This process may take up to seven days.
We use this time to verify that the request was made by you, in order to ensure the security of your data.
Your download will include:

App usage and activity information as spreadsheets or files in .json, .csv or .pdf format.
Documents, photos and videos in their original format.
Contacts, calendars, bookmarks and mail in .vcf, .ics, .html and .eml format.
Your download will not include app, book, movie, TV show or music purchases.


